# jQuery external hide not working

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a problem using hide my code is same to other but it's not working

jq.php;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>jQuery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/external.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="wawa" >Welcome Roy Gallardo !!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

external.js

```
$('#wawa').click(function(){
$('#wawa').hide();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have said, you need to wait until the DOM is ready by using [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Alternatively, you can put the script at the end of the HTML page:

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <p id="wawa" >Welcome Roy Gallardo !!</p>
    <script src="js/external.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait the DOM to be ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wawa').click(function(){
        $('#wawa').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you also wrapped your jquery code from your external into the :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

if you dont do this, jquery might not have loaded